# Tengo java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set al momento de trabajarlo orientado a objetos

Tags: java, mysql

cuento con el problema de que estoy trabajando con dos clases para el SQL una que se encarga de hacer las conexiones y hacer la estructura de las consultas al servido SQL y otra que cuenta con la Query para poder trabajarla con el patrón de diseño DAO, mi problema es que al momento de hacer un select me lanza la excepción java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set me gustaria saber el porque de esta excepcion

**Este es el ejecutarSelect que es la estructura para este mismo**

```
 public ResultSet ejecutarSelect(String select) throws SQLException{
    sen = con.createStatement();
    rs = sen.executeQuery(select);
    return rs;
}
```

**Este es el que se encarga de mandar la Query y estaba intentando de recibir datos para luego almacenarlos en una lista, pero ahí me arroja la excepción**

```
public ResultSet selectUsuario() throws SQLException {
    String query = "SELECT * FROM usuario;";

    try {
        while (c.ejecutarSelect(query).next()) {
            System.out.println(c.ejecutarSelect(query).getString(2));
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
    }

    return c.ejecutarSelect(query);
}
```

Comment: Por favor, guarda el resultado de la consulta en una variable. Estás haciendo 500 consultas a la base de datos por gusto. Cada vez que pones la línea `c.ejecutarSelect(query);` haces una nueva consulta.  Debajo de la declaración del `string`, agrega. `ResultSet result = c.ejecutarSelect(query);` y luego trabaja todo con la variable `result`.

Comment: El error te da justo porque `c.ejecutarSelect(query).getString(2)` es una nueva consulta y no has ejecutado aún `next` en esta consulta. Si sigues mi comentario anterior, el problema se solucionará.

Comment: Aparte de lo que te señala @JaimeMenéndez, lo que estás implementando no tiene nada que ver con un patrón DAO. Para tales fines, en la capa de dominio deberías tener una clase `Usuario`, una interfaz `Dao` y una clase `UsuarioDao` que implemente dicha interfaz y te devuelva objetos `Usuario`. [Aquí tienes un tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-dao-pattern) que puede ayudarte a tener una idea de cómo implementar Dao correctamente. Tu código `selectUsuario` realmente debería ser un método `getAll()` en una eventual clase `UsuarioDao`.

Comment: Si tengo un patron DAO, simplemente que aqui no mostre mis clases y como lo estoy trabajando, cuento con la clase de mi Usuario y la clase DAO y mi clase UsuarioDAO, esto es porcion de codigo y eso es una prueba para luego hacer implementacion

Comment: gracias igualmente aplicare lo que me dices y mejorare el codigo